# MailChimp Integaration with MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mailchimp

I am working on an MVC5 project, the client is interested in using MailChimp for sending emails. I have explored the MailChimp and wrappers ( MailChimp.NET ) and tried in my project as well. I tested the REST API as well and it seems to work , for example; I was able to grab lists and templates using REST API. But, still I am having issues with sending email through MailChimp.

So far, I have tried the following code and its working. Now I want to send an email to a newly registered user. Kindly give me detailed code example that How can I achieve this, because I am  totally struck here..

```
  var apiKey = "myapikey-us11";
    var listId = "mylistid"; 
    var subscribeRequest = new
                    {
                        apikey = apiKey,
                        id = listId,
                        email = new
                        {
                            email = "muhammad.waqas@seventechnology.co.uk"
                        },
                        double_optin = true,
                    };
    var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscribeRequest);
    var reqresult = CallMailChimpApi("lists/", requestJson);
```

**CallMailChimApi**

```
    private static string CallMailChimpApi(string method, string requestJson)
    {
       var endpoint = String.Format("https://{0}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/{1}", "us11", method);
        var wc = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            return wc.UploadString(endpoint, requestJson);
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            using (var sr = new      StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this function and it works successfully

```
public   void  SendEmailByApiMailChimp ()
    {
        try
        {
            string UserEmail = " Exemple@gmail.com ";
            MailChimpManager mc = new MailChimpManager("16d***********-us14");
            EmailParameter email = new EmailParameter()
            {
                Email = UserEmail
            };

            EmailParameter resulte = mc.Subscribe("yourlistnumber", email);
            var test = resulte;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ters = ex;
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.